# Add QGroupBox to the top of an QHBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgroupbox, qboxlayout

I am making a program and need to bring this QGroupBox (See image) to the top above the other two (See other image).

Thats my code:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()

    self.setWindowTitle('Wydbid - Center')
    self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)

    self.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
    self.layout().setContentsMargins(30, 30, 30, 30)

    self.setupUI()

def setupUI(self):
   datetime = QGroupBox(parent=self, title='Datum und Uhrzeit')
   datetime.setFixedHeight(150)

   action_list = QGroupBox(parent=self, title='Aktionen')
   action_list.setFixedWidth(200)

   action_list.setLayout(QGridLayout())
   action_list.layout().setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop| Qt.AlignHCenter)

   customer_note = QLabel(parent=action_list, text='Kunden')
   add_customer = ActionButton.ActionButton(parent=action_list, text='Kunde hinzufügen ➜')

   action_list.layout().addWidget(customer_note, 0, 0, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
   action_list.layout().addWidget(add_customer, 1, 0, 1, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)

   customer_list_box = QGroupBox(parent=self, title='Kundenliste')

   self.layout().addWidget(datetime)
   self.layout().addWidget(action_list)
   self.layout().addWidget(customer_list_box)
```

Now

[image]

How it should look

[image]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use a QGridLayout as main layout, then use the column *span* argument of [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-1) as "2" for the groupbox, meaning that the widget will occupy two horizontal cells in the layout.

```py
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Wydbid - Center')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)

        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        datetime = QGroupBox(parent=self, title='Datum und Uhrzeit')
        datetime.setFixedHeight(150)

        action_list = QGroupBox(parent=self, title='Aktionen')
        action_list.setFixedWidth(200)

        actionLayout = QGridLayout(action_list)
        actionLayout
        actionLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop| Qt.AlignHCenter)

        customer_note = QLabel(parent=action_list, text='Kunden')
        add_customer = ActionButton.ActionButton(parent=action_list, text='Kunde hinzufügen ➜')

        actionLayout.addWidget(customer_note, 0, 0, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        actionLayout.addWidget(add_customer, 1, 0, 1, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)

        customer_list_box = QGroupBox(parent=self, title='Kundenliste')

        mainLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(30, 30, 30, 30)
        # the "datetime" widget will occupy the first row, spanning two
        # columns of the grid
        mainLayout.addWidget(datetime, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        # the other widgets are added to the second row, placed in the
        # first and second column respectively
        mainLayout.addWidget(action_list, 1, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(customer_list_box, 1, 1)
```

<sup>Note that continuously calling `layout()` in the same function is pointless, as it creates unnecessary boilerplate and makes code less readable; as you can see, it's much clearer (and cleaner) to keep a local reference for the layout.</sup>

A grid layout might not always be the optimal solution, though, especially for widgets that could dynamically create/remove children, or whenever the layout is more complex and requires different row/column spans to achieve the wanted result.

Qt layouts can be *nested*, meaning that you can add a "child" layout to a "parent" layout. In this way, while the hierarchy of the layout is a bit more complex, allows at the same time more clarity of the whole structure.

In the following code, the main layout is a vertical one, and the two bottom widgets are added to a nested horizontal layout.

```py
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    # ...
    def setupUI(self):
        # ...
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(30, 30, 30, 30)
        mainLayout.addWidget(datetime)

        bottomLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(bottomLayout)

        bottomLayout.addWidget(action_list)
        bottomLayout.addWidget(customer_list_box)
```